# Find image link from string which is wrapped by a tag

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to extract just image link to use as background image of a div using

```
<a href="http://heartymagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/watch-derek-jeter-jordan-brand-video.png"><img src="http://heartymagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/watch-derek-jeter-jordan-brand-video.png" alt="" title="watch-derek-jeter-jordan-brand-video" width="270" height="170" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-73989" /></a>
```

PHP. I can't handle regular expressions to extract the image url. Please help me.

```
<a href="http://heartymagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/watch-derek-jeter-jordan-brand-video.png"><img src="http://heartymagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/watch-derek-jeter-jordan-brand-video.png" alt="" title="watch-derek-jeter-jordan-brand-video" width="270" height="170" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-73989" /></a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good practice is to use a DOM parser [instead of regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not) when extracting information from HTML.

One possible solution:

1. Read the HTML into a [SimpleXMLElement](http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php) object
2. Run an `xpath` query to find all `img` tags
3. Get the `src` attribute value of the first `img` tag found

Code:

```
$html = '<a href="http://heartymagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/watch-derek-jeter-jordan-brand-video.png"><img src="http://heartymagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/watch-derek-jeter-jordan-brand-video.png" alt="" title="watch-derek-jeter-jordan-brand-video" width="270" height="170" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-73989" /></a>';

// Long version
$dom        = new SimpleXMLElement($html);
$images     = $dom->xpath('//img');
$firstImage = $images[0];
$src        = $firstImage['src'];

// Short version
$src = (new SimpleXMLElement($html))->xpath('//img')[0]['src'];
```

`$src` will then contain (for both versions):

```
http://heartymagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/watch-derek-jeter-jordan-brand-video.png
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$input $ = '<a href="http://heartymagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/watch-derek-jeter-jordan-brand-video.png"><img src="http://heartymagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/watch-derek-jeter-jordan-brand-video.png" alt="" title="watch-derek-jeter-jordan-brand-video" width="270" height="170" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-73989" /></a>';
$regexp = "<img[^']*?src=\"([^']*?)\"[^']*?>"; 
if(preg_match_all("/$regexp/siU", $input, $matches)) {
   var_dump($matches[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A very crude solution... of sorts.

```
    $s='<a href="http://heartymagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/watch-derek-jeter-jordan-brand-video.png"><img src="http://heartymagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/watch-derek-jeter-jordan-brand-video.png" alt="" title="watch-derek-jeter-jordan-brand-video" width="270" height="170" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-73989" /></a>';

    preg_match('@"(http://.*)"@',$s,$m);
    echo '<pre>';
    echo str_replace(array('"','>'),'',$m[1]);
    echo '</pre>';
```